# How to divide the page in 3 parts by Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a theme layout. It will have one top bar, one content bar and one bottom bar. So none of the must overlap the other one.

Here is my attempt: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a2wzgyhp/)

```
.content {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:red;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
</nav>

<!-- Content -->
<div class="content">

</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This page will only have horizontal scroll. So I would like the `.content` covers all the free space minus the bars space. And does not overlap the bars.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your navbars are fixed, hence the overlapping. You either need to change `navbar-fixed-top` and `navbar-fixed-bottom` to `navbar-default` or add this to your CSS

```
.navbar, .content{position:relative}
```